# OpenMP 4.5 won't offload to GPU with target directive

Tags: c++, c, gpu, openmp

I am trying to make a simple GPU offloading program using openMP. However, when I try to offload it still runs on the default device, i.e. my CPU.

I have installed a compiler, g++ 7.2.0 that has CUDA support (is in on a cluster that I use). When I run the below code it shows me that it can see the 8 GPUs but when I try to offload it says that it is still on the CPU.

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <algorithm> 
#define n 10000
#define m 10000

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    double tol = 1E-10;
    double err = 1;
    size_t iter_max = 10;
    size_t iter = 0;
    bool notGPU[1] = {true};

    double Anew[n][m];
    double A[n][m];

   int target[1];
   target[0] = omp_get_initial_device();
   cout << "Total Devices: " << omp_get_num_devices() << endl;
   cout << "Target: " << target[0] << endl;


    for (int iter = 0; iter < iter_max; iter++){
        #pragma omp target 
        {
        err = 0.0;
        #pragma omp parallel for reduction(max:err)
        for (int j = 1; j < n-1; ++j){
            target[0] = omp_is_initial_device();
            for (int i = 1; i < m-1; i++){
                Anew[j][i] = 0.25 * (A[j][i+1] + A[j][i-1] + A[j-1][i] + A[j+1][i]);
                err = fmax(err, fabs(Anew[j][i] - A[j][i]));
            }

        }
        }

    }
    if (target[0]){
       cout << "not on GPU" << endl;
} else{
    cout << "On GPU" << endl;}



    return 0;
}
```

When I run this I always get that it is not on the GPU, but that there are 8 devices available.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're missing a device(id) in your #pragma omp target line:

```
#pragma omp target device(/*your device id here*/)
```

Without that, you haven't explicitly asked OpenMP to run anywhere but your CPU.

Comment: Your device id should be an integer in [0, omp_get_num_devices()).

Comment: I have done that, even using and id number that is greater than the number of devices available, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a well documented process!

You have to install some packages which look a little like:

```
sudo apt install gcc-offload-nvptx
```

You also need to add additional flags to your compilation string. I've globbed together a number of them below. Mix and match until something works, or use them as the basis for further Googling.

```
gcc -fopenmp -foffload=x86_64-intelmicemul-linux-gnu="-mavx2" -foffload=nvptx-none -foffload="-O3" -O2 test.c -fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda
```

When I last tried this with GCC in 2018 it just didn't work. At that time target offloading for OpenMP only worked with the [IBM XL](https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/xl-cpp-linux-compiler-power) compiler and OpenACC (a similar set of directives to OpenMP) only worked on the Nvidia's [PGI compiler](https://www.pgroup.com/index.htm). I find PGI to do a worse job of compiling C/C++ than the others (seems inefficient, non-standard flags), but a Community Edition is available for free and a little translating will get you running in OpenACC quickly.

IBM XL seems to do a fine job compiling, but I don't know if it's available for free.

The situation may have changed with GCC. If you find a way to get it working, I'd appreciate you leaving a comment here. My strong recommendation is that you stop trying with GCC7 and get ahold of GCC8 or GCC9. GPU offloading is a fast-moving area and you'll want the latest compilers to take best advantage of it.

Comment: IBM XL C/C++ for Linux Community Edition fully supports OpenMP 4.5 and is available at no charge. You can download it using the Download Now button at https://www.ibm.com/us-en/marketplace/xl-cpp-linux-compiler-power

Comment: `-fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda` leads to `[build] g++-10: error: unrecognized command-line option ‘-fopenmp-targets=nvptx64-nvidia-cuda’`. I wish there was a comprehensive syntax description somewhere.