# Do I have to build gcc-10 from source on Ubuntu 18.04 to have OpenMP GPU target offload?

Tags: c++, gcc, gpu, openmp, nvidia

When I use gcc-10 (and 9, 8, 7) from default repositories on Ubuntu 18.04, `omp_get_num_devices()` returns `0`, even though I have:

```
paul@desktop:~$ nvidia-smi
...
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.80.02    Driver Version: 450.80.02    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
```

Do I need a special version of gcc to get target offload capability? A special build process for my project?

Answer (score 0):

What was missing is [nvptx-tools](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/nvptx). I installed them with:

```
sudo apt install nvptx-tools libgomp-plugin-nvptx1 gcc-10-offload-nvptx
```

and `omp_get_num_devices()` returns `1` now. Unfortunately, there is still something missing preventing code with offload directives from linking.

Bear in mind that gcc-10 is not officially supported in Ubuntu 18.04, so testing repositories have to be used

Comment: Try this, perhaps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206552/openmp-4-5-wont-offload-to-gpu-with-target-directive/57224430#57224430

Comment: @Richard I tried everything I could find there. I'm still not sure, if I need a custom gcc build or just different linker options. I posted a more detailed question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64781646

Comment: Hello, did you solve this problem? Actually, I am using WSL Ubuntu and trying to use OpenMP or OpenACC for GPU parallelization but somehow I cannot use it. So I was wondering whether you could use OpenMP or OpenACC.

Comment: @ChangseokMa I didn't have time to solve this problem. I will post the solution when I find time to work on this problem.